# node express loop through session data

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I have data in a user session (not saved to a database yet) that I need to query.  I am looking to get the quantity value for each of the 3 items below, for example, I'm looking to retrieve `1` for the quantity from `{ prod: [Object], price: 100, quantity: 1 }`

how can I loop through the session data and retrieve the quantities?

```
{ products:
   { '5c60c83e84555d391aaca89b': { prod: [Object], price: 100, quantity: 1 },
     '5c60d6cd3351283d13a9f463': { prod: [Object], price: 150, quantity: 2 },
     '5c60da303351283d13a9f464': { prod: [Object], price:10, quantity: 2 } },
  cartQty: 5,
  cartTotal: 420 }
```

I've tried this which gives me the id's like `5c60c83e84555d391aaca89b`

```
    var sp = sessionCart.products;
    for (var p in sp) {
        console.log(p);
    }
```

I get nothing for output when I try this

```
         Array.from(sessionCart.products).forEach(function (child) {
             console.log(child);
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `for...in` loop slightly to show the `quantity`:

```js
var sessionCart = {
  products: {
    '5c60c83e84555d391aaca89b': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 100,
      quantity: 1
    },
    '5c60d6cd3351283d13a9f463': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 150,
      quantity: 2
    },
    '5c60da303351283d13a9f464': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 10,
      quantity: 2
    }
  },
  cartQty: 5,
  cartTotal: 420
}

var sp = sessionCart.products;
for (var p in sp) {
  console.log(sp[p].quantity);
}
```

Alternatively, use an iteration over `Object.values` and destructuring like so:

```js
var sessionCart = {
  products: {
    '5c60c83e84555d391aaca89b': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 100,
      quantity: 1
    },
    '5c60d6cd3351283d13a9f463': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 150,
      quantity: 2
    },
    '5c60da303351283d13a9f464': {
      prod: [Object],
      price: 10,
      quantity: 2
    }
  },
  cartQty: 5,
  cartTotal: 420
};

Object.values(sessionCart.products).forEach(({ quantity }) => console.log(quantity));
```

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is that you're trying to loop through the values of an object and pull out a property (quantity) of each object.

You could use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get just the values of the object as an array and loop through that.

```
Object.values(sessionCart.products).forEach(function (product) {
  console.log(product.quantity)
})
```